# Contar e comparar numero de chaves e valores entre objetos

Tags: javascript, lógica, objetos

Estou utilizando objetos JavaScript para transcrever a interface de um app, contudo, gostaria de criar uma ferramenta para transcrição colaborativa mas não sei como proceder.

De maneira simplista o objeto possui índices, itens ou sub-índices com itens e todos os seus valores são `strings`.

**Exemplo:**

```
// objeto original
var i18n = {
    // índice único
    title: "Titulo qualquer",

    // índice com sub-índices
    words: {
       logout: "Encerrar sessão",
       open: "abrir",
       close: "fechar"
    },

    // índice com sub-índices e itens
    combo: {
       btn_top: "De volta ao topo",
       err_conn: {
          dberr: "Erro ao conectar a base de dados",
          reqerr: "Erro ao requisitar recurso"
       }
    }
}
```

Assumindo que este objeto seja o "original" o objeto a ter seus valores modificados seria uma cópia deste.

Como comparar o objeto editado em relação ao original apresentando esta diferença em porcentagem **`%`** ?

Comment: A percentagem de cada propriedade é igual?

Comment: A porcentagem global dos itens modificados na "copia" em relação ao "original

Comment: Lauro, se pensares em cada nivel de profundidade como uma arvore como queres fazer? neste caso tens 3 propriedades no primeiro nivel. Cada uma vale 33,333% ?

Comment: Na verdade o objeto é bem maior que o exemplo, se eu usar `Object.keys(i18n)` retorno o número de chaves no "primeiro nível" pensei em dividir o total por **100** contudo os itens ou sub-itens dentro destes índices de "primeiro nível" não me permitem expressar esta grandeza assim

Comment: Não permitem porquê? a maneira mais simples é dar uma percentagem a cada propriedade e as suas subpropriedades uma fração dessa `%`. Se não adoptas este modelo tens de ter regras para o peso/valor de todas as propriedades

Comment: Pois bem acredito não chegar a uma lógica de como comparar estas diferenças. Para buscar todas as chaves passaria `Object.keys()` no objeto e depois neste resultado e posteriormente nos resultados deste. E como faria esta verificação/comparação? Como subtrairia a porcentagem do que foi modificado em relação ao "original" ?

Comment: Pois há várias maneiras, por isso pergunto. As mais simples são: `#1` cada sub-propriedade é uma fração igual do total de propriedades. `#2` cada propriedade tem o peso da sua descendência.

Comment: Qual dos modelos ^ preferes?

Comment: Acho que a `#2` pois o o percentual deve expressar o total contido no objeto? não?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer isso de maneira recursiva, e assim podes usar qualquer tipo de objeto sem ter de configurar N loops para esse objeto específico.

```js
function compare(objA, objB){
    return Object.keys(objA).reduce(function(arr, prop){
        if (typeof objA[prop] == 'string' || typeof objA[prop] == 'number') {
            return arr.concat(objA[prop] === objB[prop])
        }
        else return arr.concat(compare(objA[prop], objB[prop]));
    }, [])
}

var changes = compare(original, changed);
var percentageEqual = changes.filter(Boolean).length * 100 / changes.length;
```

Usando o teu exemplo:

```js
function compare(objA, objB) {
  return Object.keys(objA).reduce(function(arr, prop) {
    if (typeof objA[prop] == 'string' || typeof objA[prop] == 'number') {
      return arr.concat(objA[prop] === objB[prop])
    } else return arr.concat(compare(objA[prop], objB[prop]));
  }, [])
}

// objeto original
var i18n1 = {
  // índice único
  title: "Titulo qualquer",
  // índice com sub-índices
  words: {
    logout: "Encerrar sessão",
    open: "abrir",
    close: "fechar"
  },
  // índice com sub-índices e itens
  combo: {
    btn_top: "De volta ao topo",
    err_conn: {
      dberr: "Erro ao conectar a base de dados",
      reqerr: "Erro ao requisitar recurso"
    }
  }
}

// objeto original
var i18n2 = {
  // índice único
  title: "Titulo qualquer modificado",
  // índice com sub-índices
  words: {
    logout: "Encerrar sessão",
    open: "abrir janela",
    close: "fechar"
  },
  // índice com sub-índices e itens
  combo: {
    btn_top: "De volta ao topo",
    err_conn: {
      dberr: "Erro ao conectar a base de dados",
      reqerr: "Reco reco"
    }
  }
}

var changes = compare(i18n1, i18n2);
var percentageEqual = changes.filter(Boolean).length * 100 / changes.length;
console.log(percentageEqual.toFixed(3) + '%');
```

Outra variante como referiste *"retornar também um array contendo as palavras|frases não editadas (em um índice com o caminho completo da propriedade dentro do objeto)"* seria assim:

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1a22mz0p/

Comment: Gracias. Caso eu queira retornar também um array contendo as palavras|frases não editadas (em um índice com o caminho completo da propriedade dentro do objeto) seria possível no seu exemplo?

Comment: @LauroMoraes essa funcionalidade não dá com o exemplo como está, mas mudando um pouco já dá. Ando meio apertado de tempo, mas depois faço um edit com essa ideia. O principal é usar recursividade, assim fica mais compacto e escalável.

Comment: Ok. Gostei muito da solução que apresentas-te, modifiquei um pouco e consegui trazer palavras editadas e as não editadas porém sem o caminho no objeto :(

Comment: @LauroMoraes juntei à resposta

Answer (score 0):

Sabendo que: o objeto "**original**" possuí propriedades e que estas possuem outras propriedades em si e todos os valores finais são do tipo `string` e sem abordar questões de validação (fora do escopo da questão) um método viável seria o seguinte.

- iterar todo objeto e suas propriedades para recurar todos os valores (`string`)
- criar um índice de porcentagem a partir do total de valores do objeto "**original**"
- iterar o total de valores do objeto "**original**" e do "**clone**" para verificar igualdade e com base nesta (ou na falta dela) incrementar índices usados para montar a porcentagem de total concluído e restando (a concluir)

A seguinte abordagem cumpre a questão.

**Exemplo:**

```
// objeto original
var i18n1 = {
    // índice único
    title: "Titulo qualquer",
    // índice com sub-índices
    words: {
       logout: "Encerrar sessão",
       open: "abrir",
       close: "fechar"
    },
    // índice com sub-índices e itens
    combo: {
       btn_top: "De volta ao topo",
       err_conn: {
          dberr: "Erro ao conectar a base de dados",
          reqerr: "Erro ao requisitar recurso"
       }
    }
}

// objeto original
var i18n2 = {
    // índice único
    title: "Titulo qualquer modificado",
    // índice com sub-índices
    words: {
       logout: "Encerrar sessão",
       open: "abrir janela",
       close: "fechar"
    },
    // índice com sub-índices e itens
    combo: {
       btn_top: "De volta ao topo",
       err_conn: {
          dberr: "Erro ao conectar a base de dados",
          reqerr: "Reco reco"
       }
    }
}

// função para percorrer o object
var get_values = function(obj){
    var strings = [];
    // initialize loops
    for (k in obj) {
         // values from first level
         if ( typeof obj[k] === 'string' ) {
              strings.push(obj[k])
         }
         // first level keys search
         if ( typeof obj[k] === 'object' ) {
              for (k1 in obj[k] ) {
                   // values from second level
                   if ( typeof obj[k][k1] === 'string' ) {
                        strings.push(obj[k][k1])
                   }
                   // second level keys search
                   if ( typeof obj[k][k1] === 'object' ) {
                        for (k2 in obj[k][k1]) {
                             // values from third level
                             if ( typeof obj[k][k1][k2] === 'string' ) {
                                  strings.push(obj[k][k1][k2])
                             }
                             // third level keys search
                             if ( typeof obj[k][k1][k2] === 'object' ) {
                                  for (k3 in obj[k][k1][k2]) {
                                       // values from fourt level
                                       if ( typeof obj[k][k1][k2][k3] === 'string' ) {
                                            strings.push(obj[k][k1][k2][k3])
                                       }
                                       /*
                                       if ( typeof obj[k][k1][k2][k3] === 'object' ) {
                                            console.info(obj[k][k1][k2][k3])
                                       }
                                       */
                                  }
                             }
                        }
                   }
              }
         }
    }
    return strings;
};

// função para comparar
var compare = function(obj1, obj2){
    var indx1 = get_values(obj1),
        indx2 = get_values(obj2),
        len   = indx1.length;

    var percentage = (100/indx1.length),
        yes = 0,    // traduzidas
        not = 0;    // faltando
    // loop
    for (;len--;) {
         if ( indx1[len] !== indx2[len] ) {
              yes++
         } else {
              not++
         }
    }
    var done = ( (percentage * yes) === 100.00 || (percentage * yes) === 0.00) ? (percentage * yes).toFixed(0) : (percentage * yes).toFixed(2);
    var need = ( (percentage * not) === 100.00 || (percentage * not) === 0.00) ? (percentage * not).toFixed(0) : (percentage * not).toFixed(2);

    return {
        done: done +'%',
        need: need +'%'
    }
};

// buscar resultado
var res = compare(i18n1, i18n2);

// printar
console.log('tradução concluída: ' + res.done);
// output: tradução concluída: 42.86%

console.log('faltando traduzir: ' + res.need);
// output: faltando traduzir: 57.14%
```

Contudo não estou certo se a quantidade de **loops** usando `for` é o melhor caminho ou se há um método menos "custoso" por isso deixo a questão em aberto para correções, sugestões ou uma resposta mais qualificada que venha a surgir.

Grato por qualquer ajuda.